# data.table: Numeric column name

Tags: r, data.table

Here's the data.table Im working with:

```
> head(dataTable)
     persnr      1993      1994
1: 60487416 0.5777598        NA
2: 60487511        NA  5.245855
3: 60488034 0.5777598 23.100167
4: 60488147 0.5777598        NA
5: 60488240 0.5777598 23.100167
6: 60488338 0.5777598 23.100167
```

Having the column years numeric is quite useful, as I can simply iterate through these. It however has a drawback:

```
dataTable[is.na(1993),]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: persnr,1993,1994
```

It mistakes the `1993` for an integer, instead of using it as the object name. Otherwise I can't explain how it would come up with zero rows that satisfy this condition. How can I check for `NA` values when the column name is numeric?

Comment: Try: dataTable[ is.na(\`1993\`) ]

Comment: Perfect. If I may ask a follow-up: What if I saved `x <- 1993`, for reasons of iteration. `dataTable[is.na(\`x\`)]` won't work.

Comment: It's inelegant, but you could do this:

`x <- quote( is.na(\`1993\`) )`
`dataTable[ eval(x) ]`

You are still left with a problem of creating the RHS of x. You can also use `?parse`

Comment: Maybe its better if I just post my whole problem, perhaps Im just approaching this whole thing from a wrong way in the `r` perspective: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684945/compute-panel-differences

Answer (score 0):

You may want to treat your data.frame like a matrix and use the apply function to find the NA values:

> apply(dataTable,1,is.na)

That will be faster than iterating through columns.

If you want to find the rows with any NA values you could do:

> apply(dataTable,1,function(x){any(is.na(x))})