# Compute panel differences

Tags: r, data.table

I have some panel data. For this data, I want to compute the differences for every year for every group, if the group had observations in both years.

Here's the data:

```
> head(statistics)
     persnr year NOBS     value
1: 61961225 1993    1 0.5777598
2: 62037645 1993    1 0.5777598
3: 62181514 1993    1 0.5777598
4: 62499451 1993    1 0.5777598
5: 62649247 1993    1 0.5777598
6: 62744472 1993    1 0.5777598
```

Where `persnr` is the groupid for the panel. And my current approach was something along the lines of

```
dataTable = data.table(cast(statistics, persnr ~ year, value='totalWage'))
# y is the second year. Iterate over that
for (y in tail(unique(statistics[, jahr]), n=-1)):
  # get the first year
  x <- y - 1  
  dataTable[!is.na(`x`) & !is.na(`y`), `y`-`x`]
}
```

However, I cant use the `\`x`` scheme to access the columns. What'd be an "R-ish" way of solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want to use data.table here:

```
statistics[ by=persnr, order(year), list( year=year[-1], diff = diff(value) ) ]
```

This would give you a data.table wit columns: `persnr`, `year` and `diff`.  You can change the `-1` to `-N` to shift which of the differences get omitted, the first or the last.

Comment: You don't use `order` in `data.table`. Either use `setkey` or `setorder`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, you can, when you don't want to change the order of the original data.table.